# MainView.xib not present in tab bar app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, default, uitabbar

I'm new to tab bar applications and all the tutorials I find need to change something in MainView.xib, but when I create a new tab bar app (in Xcode 4), there is no MainView.xib. The only ones there are:

FirstViewController_iPhone.xib
First...iPad.xib
Second...iPhone.xib
Second...iPad.xib

Is it supposed to be there and it's missing, or could you point me to a tutorial that does not require Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

The method of setting the Main Interface has changed over the last few revisions of iOS. You can set it in your project settings or in code, as is done by default:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[[FooFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[FooSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[[FooFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[FooSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FooSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

}

Since it's a tab bar application, the app creates a UITabBarController in code, then sets its view controllers to instances of the FirstViewController and SecondViewController classes.

If you want to follow the book, uou can delete the contents of this method and create a xib called MainWindow.xib, with a tab bar controller in it and two children, the aforementioned instances. Click on your target settings, and on the Summary page, under **iPhone / iPod Deployment Info** you should see a drop down menu labelled **Main Interface**. Set its value to MainWindow.xib to have it load when the app runs.